# undefined name 'widget' in stateful widget flutter

Tags: flutter

Suddenly i started facing this error in my all project. Even I tried to create new project but failed too.

I am using stateful widget and when I try to access class variable using widget then i face this error.

Flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.7)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.50.1)
 
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

I tried flutter clean but no luck.

[image]

Comment: try running flutter clean or reinstall flutter. Your flutter sdk might be corrupt or the flutter extension in vscode isn't working properly

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, yes were right. somehow my sdk was corrupted. I solved it by changing branch forcefully. Thank you @Uni

Comment: please post the whole class (full code).